# Show a tooltip/popover on a <area>

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I'm creating a website using bootstrap and want from tags `<area>` (within image map) display a tooltip or popover as if they were markers of a map.

I've seen documentation using a `<button>` tag for popover, would it be possible to do so from an `<area>`?

Comment: The tooltip will "work", but it won't be the over the defined area since areas are not visible: http://www.codeply.com/go/y1nltmzO0O

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used this jQuery plugin in the past.
Find it quite useful and configurable.

http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/